# Using empty TextView with minlines=x to add space viable?

Tags: android

Are there any **bad sides** to adding space to a layout by using empty `TextViews` with `minlines=1` instead of using `margin`, `padding`, or

`<Space
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="10dp/>`

**EDIT**

Here is a picture of an example, the red arrows points to where I have used empty `TextView`s

[image]

Comment: What do you want exactly? can you post a picture of what you want or something?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS check out my edit

Comment: And what's the problem? You want to create empty text views?

Comment: My question is if there are any downsides to using empty TextViews in my app to add space between sections instead of using margin, padding or such.

Comment: Theres no problem on that issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I didn't misunderstood you, you want a blank space, so you can use :

[`Space`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space.html)

```
<Space
android:layout_width="1dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"/>
```

[`View`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

```
<View
android:layout_width="1dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent" // or 0dp
android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

You can alter the `width` and `height` as you like.

Comment: That is right, I would prefer using a TextView with minlines for simplicity and consistency instead tho. So unless it slows down the performance of the app or there are any other major downsides I guess it's viable.

Comment: If you use text view  you will slow down your app, also you will be using memory unnecessarily, if you want I can put  text view if you want but it's better view and space

Comment: Alright then I will use space or view instead, thanks

Comment: @SimonAndersson if it helped mark this questions as an asnwer and upvote this question, so other users can use this if they face the same problem as you :)